# Angular nativeElement.scrollTop has weird behavior

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, ionic4

Can you tell me why `this.myScrollContainer.nativeElement.scrollTop` doesn't get the assigned value of this `this.myScrollContainer.nativeElement.scrollHeight`? What is hapening here?

.ts

```
 @ViewChild('scrollMe', { static: false }) private myScrollContainer: ElementRef;

  scrollToBottom(): void {
     this.myScrollContainer.nativeElement.scrollTop =  this.myScrollContainer.nativeElement.scrollHeight;
   }
```

.html

```
<div class="row2" #scrollMe>
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col>
          <app-school></app-school>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </div>
```

.scss

```
.content {
    ion-grid {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        height: 100% !important;
    }

    .row1 {
        flex: 2 !important;
    }

    .row2 {
        flex: 5 !important;
        overflow: scroll !important;
    }
}
```

Gif - click to see it on a big screen

[image]

Comment: Can we see how and where you call `scrollToBottom`?

Comment: @ConnorsFan Please see line `161` on the above gif.

Comment: My suggestion: call `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` to update the view before calling `scrollToBottom()`.

Comment: @ConnorsFan That is unnecessary overhead to the component since it'll re-run the change detection for the whole component. But `setTimeout()` is more efficient here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems a bug on Angular when accessing the native DOM elements. I have done like below and working perfectly fine now. i.e. use `setTimeout()`

```
scrollToBottom(): void {
   setTimeout(() => { this.myScrollContainer.nativeElement.scrollTop = this.myScrollContainer.nativeElement.scrollHeight; }, 1);
  }
```